# Accessing sharedPreferences inside Retrofit Interceptor

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

Here is a Retrofit Interceptor used to inject automatically a token inside requests. I'm trying to get this token from `sharedPreferences` but `getSharedPreferences` is not available there.

**How can i retrieve my token from sharedpreferences inside this Interceptor ?**

```
import android.preference.PreferenceManager
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response

class ServiceInterceptor: Interceptor {

    var token : String = "";

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()

        if(request.header("No-Authentication") == null){

            if (request.url.toString().contains("/user/signin") === false) {
                // Add Authorization header only if it's not the user signin request.

                // Get token from shared preferences
                val sharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences()
                token = sharedPreference.getString("token")

                if (!token.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    val finalToken = "Bearer " + token
                    request = request.newBuilder()
                        .addHeader("Authorization", finalToken)
                        .build()
                }

            }

        }

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

}
```

Comment: perhaps you might wanna pass the instance in the `ServiceInterceptor`s constructor

Comment: [If you're currently using `SharedPreferences` to store data, consider migrating to DataStore instead.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple solution for this in **Kotlin** – just **copy & paste** the code into a new `AppPreferences.kt` file and **follow the 4 TODO steps** outlined in the code:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.core.content.edit

object AppPreferences {
    private var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null

    // TODO step 1: call `AppPreferences.setup(applicationContext)` in your MainActivity's `onCreate` method
    fun setup(context: Context) {
        // TODO step 2: set your app name here
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("<YOUR_APP_NAME>.sharedprefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    }

    // TODO step 4: replace these example attributes with your stored values
    var heightInCentimeters: Int?
        get() = Key.HEIGHT.getInt()
        set(value) = Key.HEIGHT.setInt(value)

    var birthdayInMilliseconds: Long?
        get() = Key.BIRTHDAY.getLong()
        set(value) = Key.BIRTHDAY.setLong(value)

    private enum class Key {
        HEIGHT, BIRTHDAY; // TODO step 3: replace these cases with your stored values keys

        fun getBoolean(): Boolean? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getBoolean(name, false) else null
        fun getFloat(): Float? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getFloat(name, 0f) else null
        fun getInt(): Int? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getInt(name, 0) else null
        fun getLong(): Long? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getLong(name, 0) else null
        fun getString(): String? = if (sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)) sharedPreferences!!.getString(name, "") else null

        fun setBoolean(value: Boolean?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putBoolean(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setFloat(value: Float?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putFloat(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setInt(value: Int?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putInt(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setLong(value: Long?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putLong(name, value) } } ?: remove()
        fun setString(value: String?) = value?.let { sharedPreferences!!.edit { putString(name, value) } } ?: remove()

        fun exists(): Boolean = sharedPreferences!!.contains(name)
        fun remove() = sharedPreferences!!.edit { remove(name) }
    }
}
```

Now from anywhere within your app you can **get a value** like this:

```
val heightInCentimeters: Int? = AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters
val heightOrDefault: Int = AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters ?: 170
```

**Setting a value** to the `SharedPreferences` is just as easy:

```
AppPreferences.heightInCentimeters = 160 // sets a new value
```

The above is extracted from my [FitnessTracker project](https://github.com/Flinesoft/FitnessTracker-Android). See [this file](https://github.com/Flinesoft/FitnessTracker-Android/blob/main/app/src/main/kotlin/com/flinesoft/fitnesstracker/globals/AppPreferences.kt) for a full example.

Answer (score 1):

As coroutineDispatcher has commented you should pass in the shared preferences into the interceptor's constructor and hold a reference to them.

Try this:

```kotlin
class ServiceInterceptor(private val prefs: SharedPreferences): Interceptor {
    
    val token: String get() = prefs.getString("token")
    
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
    
        if(request.header("No-Authentication") == null){
    
            if (request.url.toString().contains("/user/signin") === false) {
                // Add Authorization header only if it's not the user signin request.
                request = token
                    .takeUnless { it.isNullOrEmpty }
                    ?.let {
                        request.newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $it")
                            .build()
                    }
                    ?: request
            }
        }
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
    
}
```

The interceptor now takes in a reference to shared preferences so the dependency has been inverted and it can allow for easy testing by stubbing the passed SharedPreferences.

And it can be instanatiated like this:

```
ServiceInterceptor(PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `singleton class` for `SharedPreference` and then you can access it from any `class` you want.

**Example**

```
class SessionManager private constructor(context:Context) {
  private val prefs:SharedPreferences
  private val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor
  var token:String
  get() {
    return prefs.getString("token", "")
  }
  set(token) {
    editor.putString("token", token)
    editor.apply()
  }
  init{
    prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Your_Preference_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    editor = prefs.edit()
  }
  companion object {
    private val jInstance:SessionManager
    @Synchronized fun getInstance(context:Context):SessionManager {
      if (jInstance != null)
      {
        return jInstance
      }
      else
      {
        jInstance = SessionManager(context)
        return jInstance
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now you have to pass `context` in `constructor` of `ServiceInterceptor` and you can access `SharedPreference` like following.

```
val token = SessionManager.getInstance(context).token;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

val token = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences().getToken("","")

```
builder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()
            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }
        return builder.build()
```

Comment: PreferenceManager is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I needed to store JWT token in my application and I was struggling with the same issue and came up with a solution, it may be useful for some of you.

It's achievable with dependency injection using **Dagger Hilt**.

Inject `ServiceInterceptor` to `RetrofitClient`

```
class RetrofitClient @Inject constructor(
    private val serviceInterceptor: ServiceInterceptor,
) {
    val api: ApiInterface by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(
                GsonConverterFactory.create(
                    GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
                        LocalDate::class.java,
                        JsonDeserializer { json, _, _ ->
                            LocalDate.parse(
                                json.asJsonPrimitive.asString
                            )
                        }).create(),
                )
            )
            .baseUrl(Constants.URL)
            .client(
                OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(OkHttpProfilerInterceptor())
                    .addInterceptor(serviceInterceptor)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

Inject `SharedPreferences` to `ServiceInterceptor`

```
class ServiceInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
) : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val token = sharedPreferences.getString("JWT_AUTH_TOKEN", "")

        var request = chain.request()
        if (request.header("No-Authentication") == null) {
            if (token != null && token.isNotEmpty()) {
                val bearerToken = "Bearer $token"

                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", bearerToken)
                    .build()
            }
        }

        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Define Module for dagger hilt:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ConfigModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("JWT_AUTH_TOKEN", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideServiceInterceptor(sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences): ServiceInterceptor =
        ServiceInterceptor(sharedPreferences)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofitClient(serviceInterceptor: ServiceInterceptor): RetrofitClient =
        RetrofitClient(serviceInterceptor)
}
```

That's it, you should be good to go with injecting your `RetrofitClient` into your repository like that:

```
class CustomRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val retrofitClient: RetrofitClient,
)
```

If you want to write to `SharedPreferences` from other classes just inject it:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LoginUserFragment @Inject constructor(
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences,
)
```

And then to write your JWT token to `SharedPreferences` use code:

```
with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
    putString("JWT_AUTH_TOKEN", token)
    apply()
}
```